# cannot sort row with day title in codeigniter mysql

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a table structure like this:

```
ID       title             start         user_id
235   MORNING      2019-07-28 00:00:00    1234
238   AFTERNOON    2019-07-28 00:00:00    1234    
239   EVENING      2019-07-28 00:00:00    1234
240   NIGHT        2019-07-28 00:00:00    1234
241   MORNING      2019-07-29 00:00:00    1234
244   AFTERNOON    2019-07-29 00:00:00    1234
245   EVENING      2019-07-29 00:00:00    1234
247   NIGHT        2019-07-29 00:00:00    1234
```

I'm getting result like this

```
28-07-2019
AFTERNOON
MORNING
EVENING 
NIGHT 
29-07-2019
...
...
```

but what i want is my record sorted like this

```
28-07-2019
MORNING 
AFTERNOON 
EVENING 
NIGHT
29-07-2019
...
...
```

what i have tried so far is :

```
 $results =  $this->db->select('*')->where('user_id',$user_id)->order_by('id','DESC')->group_by('start')->get('data_test')->result();
       foreach ($results as $result){

       }
       return $results;
```

I used this query but it also didn't work:

```
->order_by(array('id',"CASE title WHEN '' THEN 0 WHEN 'MORNING' THEN 1 WHEN 'AFTERNOON' THEN 2 WHEN 'EVENING' THEN 3 WHEN 'NIGHT' THEN 4 END asc")
```

Comment: You can simply do 
`$this->db->select('*')->where('user_id',$user_id)->order_by('id','ASC')->group_by('start');`

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik :FOR GETTING DATA FROM TABLE.

Comment: Simply orderBy `id ASC` , you will get what you want as per your data\

Comment: no data is not sorted by id and morning,afternoon....night. presently all morning, afternoon, evening, night data gets grouped by

Comment: Try this
 `order_by(array('title',"FIELD (title, 'MORNING', 'AFTERNOON', 'EVENING', 'NIGHT') ASC")`

Comment: $results =  $this->db->select('*')->where('user_id',$user_id)->order_by(array('title',"FIELD (title, 'MORNING', 'AFTERNOON', 'EVENING', 'NIGHT') ASC")->group_by('start'))->get('tablename')->result();  this query is not running

Comment: Then try something like this,
 `$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM data_test WHERE userid = $user_id GROUP BY start ORDER BY FIELD(title, 'MORNING', 'AFTERNOON', 'EVENING', 'NIGHT') ASC')->result();`

Comment: There is no need for any GROUP BY here. As @bhuvneshpattnaik mentions, `ORDER BY id` is all you need.

Answer (score 0):

By way of demonstration...

```
<?php

/*
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,title VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,start DATE NOT NULL
,user_id INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(235,'MORNING','2019-07-28 00:00:00',1234),
(238,'AFTERNOON','2019-07-28 00:00:00',1234),
(239,'EVENING','2019-07-28 00:00:00',1234),
(240,'NIGHT','2019-07-28 00:00:00',1234),
(241,'MORNING','2019-07-29 00:00:00',1234),
(244,'AFTERNOON','2019-07-29 00:00:00',1234),
(245,'EVENING','2019-07-29 00:00:00',1234),
(247,'NIGHT','2019-07-29 00:00:00',1234);
*/

require('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');



$query = "
SELECT id
     , title
     , start
     , user_id
  FROM my_table
 ORDER
    BY id;
";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

$start = '';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

if($start == $row['start']){echo '';} else {echo '<br/>'.$row['start'];}
echo '<br/>'.$row['title'];
$start = $row['start'];

}

?>
```

Outputs:

```
2019-07-28
MORNING
AFTERNOON
EVENING
NIGHT
2019-07-29
MORNING
AFTERNOON
EVENING
NIGHT
```

...and not a GROUP BY clause in sight.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but if sometime i get id of night to 234 instead of 240 then the result is not correctly displayed.

Comment: In which case, the specification is incomplete

Comment: There is a scenario when in my db the id of days event get changed for eg. id of night gets updated to 234 instead of 240 then Night comes on top of Morning and the sorting order is disturbed,

Comment: We can only ask the question asked; that's how SO works.

Comment: 'Answer' - coffee required

Comment: You are just giving Core PHP answer which is further based on the fact that
Data will always be in same format as given in the question only, Not a generalised and appropriate answer at all.

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik It's appropriate to the question that was asked. Whether or not it's easily adaptable to the more generalised problem, depends on the nature of that problem, which has not, as yet, been clearly articulated.

Comment: Its (question) as simple as to understand sorting,

@user3653474 just gave an example how the data is structured in DB